# Function returning function is not allowed in typedef FOO(BAR)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, typedef

I have a problem with a [piece of code from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/404246/194976). I'm actually not sure what that syntax is even supposed to mean:

```
typedef NTSTATUS( WINAPI* PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION ) ( 
  __in       SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,     
  __inout    PVOID SystemInformation, 
  __in       ULONG SystemInformationLength, 
  __out_opt  PULONG ReturnLength    
);
```

Normally, it's `typedef oldtype newtype`. In the above syntax I see no `newtype`. The ide marks `PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION` red with the message: *Error: function returning function is not allowed.*.

When I hover the `PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION` I get this (and I had to rewrite the whole tooltip text here...):

```
typedef <error-type> (__stdcall *PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass, PVOID SystemInformation, ULONG SystemInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength)
```

If I try to compile, this is the error regarding this line (which causes lot of other errors elsewhere):

```
1>...\nostealfocus\nostealfocus\nostealfocus.cpp(6): error C2059: syntax error : '__stdcall'
```

So...

1. What does this syntax mean? What would more general syntax like this do?
2. Can I fix this problem? (I really need to!)

Comment: 1) It is a typedef defining a function pointer.  2) What is the actual *compiler* error?

Comment: Didn't try to compile. I'll try and update my question - thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: See this simple example: http://ideone.com/x29p7s  Your definition uses more parameters and return type, but it boils down to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I met the exact same issue, and for me, it was the definition of `NTSTATUS` which was not found.
This would cause `typedef NTSTATUS( WINAPI* PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION )` to be interpreted as typedef of "function returning function", i.e.:

`typedef func( __stdcall PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION )(...)`

rather than:

`typedef LONG( __stdcall PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION )(...)`

since `NTSTATUS` is actually a typedef to `LONG`.

My workaround was to replace the function return type from `NTSTATUS` to `LONG` (but ideally includes should be fixed so that `NTSTATUS` is resolved).

Comment: This Answer came through for me in the clutch.